# Maven not generating javadocs as part of site

Tags: java, maven

OK, I have tried "almost" everything by now but still cannot get "mvn site" to generate (and finally link) javadocs. I last used the following reference : http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/usage.html. I am using maven version 3.0.3

Relevant portion of POM ("reporting" element is a child of "project" element.)

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: Which version of the maven-site-plugin are you using?

Comment: there is no explicit site plugin configuration in my POM. Could that be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5221 which immediately shows that you should lock plugin versions in your pom.xml: it'll make your project more stable and doesn't depend on predefined versions of the Maven distribution. If you would have used a more recent version of Maven you would have never discovered this.
So locking the maven-site-plugin to a 3.x version (most recent is now 3.4) should fix your problem.